# How to convert the System output of console to HTML file with proper indentations

Tags: java, html, collections

I have a Shopping  cart app, it is a program that comes under OOAD(Object Oriented Design and Analysis) that has product, lineitems, order and customer classes. I want to transfer the contents of the last class customer to HTML file.i have made an attempt but it is not proper with indentations . How to create one ?

code :

```
public class CustomerHTML {


    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{

    Customer customer = new Customer("pizza","Sucheta");

    Order neworder = new Order("1","9/9/2017",OrderStatus.PLACED );

    customer.placeOrder(neworder);

    addLineItemsToOrder(neworder);

    printDetails(customer);


    public  static void addLineItemsToOrder (Order newOrder){

        Product pizza = new Product("1", "pizza", 250, 10);
        Product sandwich = new Product ("2","sandwich",100,20);

        LineItem item1 = new LineItem (pizza, 3,"1");
        LineItem item2 = new LineItem (sandwich, 2 , "2");
        LineItem item3 = new LineItem (pizza,2,"1");

        newOrder.addToCart(item1);
        newOrder.addToCart(item2);
        newOrder.addToCart(item3);



    }

    public static void printDetails(Customer customer) throws 
       FileNotFoundException{
        System.out.println("Customer  name= "+ customer.getCustName() + 
        "\tCustomer Id = "+ customer.getCustId());
        System.out.println();
        List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();


        orders = customer.noOfOrderPlaced();
        for(Order order : orders){
            System.out.println(order.toString());
            System.out.println("\nTotal Shopping Cart cost =" 
         +order.checkOutCost());


            PrintStream pr=new PrintStream("three.html");
            pr.println("<html>");
            pr.println("<head>");

            pr.println("<title> DMART Invoice");
            pr.println("</title>");
            pr.println("</head>");
            pr.println("<body>");
            pr.println("<h1>");
            pr.println("<\n>");
            pr.println("Customer  name= "+ customer.getCustName() + 
              "\tCustomer Id = "+ customer.getCustId());
            pr.println(order.toString());
            pr.println("<\n>");
            pr.println("\nTotal Shopping Cart cost =" 
           +order.checkOutCost());
            pr.println("</h1>");
            pr.println("</body>");
            pr.println("</html>");
            pr.close();

        }

   }
```

}

Its HTML Version - 
[image: snapshot]

Comment: `"<\n>"` is not going to do what you hope - this results in an invalid empty (bar a new line) tag. You perhaps want `"<br/>"` as a quick and dirty line break, but further formatting is better achieved with CSS. Note that HTML will basically remove all newlines and multiple consecutive spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `"\n"` with `<br>` because to break line in `HTML` `<br>` is used and `&nbsp;` for non-breaking space. Writing `HTML` code in `.java` file is very tedious task instead of writing HTML inside `.java` file you can do all the HTML stuff in `JSP`.